# Solr: how to index date and time

Tags: solr, lucene

I have Solr 7.2.1 and in my managed-schema.xml file I have a field which represents date object of type "pDate".

Now I need to index also the time of the day, but I saw I can't search for the time with "pDate" field type. If I query solr searching for `my_date_field:[2018-03-12T00:00:00.000Z TO *]` it works; instead if i search `[2018-03-12T12:00:00.000Z TO *]` I can't find any results.

so, basically, what type is better to use to achieve that ? Is the field type the origin of the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,
I had to set $SOLR_TIMEZONE variable in the "solr.in" config file, but the correct value was not "CEST" but "Europe/Rome" for me

Answer (score 0):

Solr Ref Guide says: "Solr’s date fields (DatePointField, DateRangeField and the deprecated TrieDateField) represent "dates" as a point in time with millisecond precision." So the field can not be the origin of your problem.

Check the format "12/03/2018T12:00:00.000Z". Is is really correct? I only know dates formatted like "2018-03-12T12:00:00.000Z". See here [Date Formatting](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/working-with-dates.html#date-formatting)

Also find the document in Solr Admin UI and inspect the JSON response. What is the value of my_date_field?

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in my question. I typed with the "/" character, but in my code I use "-" correctly.

Comment: So check the value really stored in my_date_field of the document(s). Maybe it is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: 12-03-2018 is still not correct. It has to be 2018-03-12.

Comment: I found the problem, my solr installation is in CET timezone, instead of UTC, and it automatically subtract 1 hours from my data source dates.  But if I place it at UTC, than I have problems with execution time and delta queries any suggests ?

Comment: Did you set  $SOLR_TIMEZONE?

Comment: Yes, I did set that variable in solr.cmd.in And that is the point. Because now solr is correctly paired with my timezone and I can correctly do delta imports based on time delta, but it fails when I query the index. 
Reading in the documentation I found I can't specify time zone in the date queries, so I have to manually adjust my query, am I right ??  https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-dates.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166949/discussion-between-fjordo-and-holger-thurow).